# fadeOut with jQuery .removeClass

Tags: jquery, css, class

Good day! I'm new here! For now, sorry for stupid :-)

Function: Header becomes visible when scrolling down. And hidden when you scroll to the top. Code works but I can't make soft fade-outs with removeClass.
Can someone help me?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {  

  var header_fixed = jQuery(".header-fixed")
  jQuery( header_fixed ).wrap( "<div class='header-f-wrapper'></div>" );
  var header_f_wrapper = jQuery (".header-f-wrapper");
  var height = jQuery(".et-l--header").height()+(20);


    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ 
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>height){
    header_f_wrapper.addClass("header-show");
    }
    else{
    header_f_wrapper.removeClass("header-show");
    }
  })
})
</script>
<style>
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}  
.header-f-wrapper {
display:none;
} 
.header-f-wrapper {
z-index: 999; /* display at the top */ 
position: fixed;
width:100%;  
top: 0;
-webkit-animation: fadein 0.9s ease-in; 
-moz-animation: fadein 0.9s ease-in;
animation: fadein 0.9s ease-in;
}
.header-f-wrapper.header-show {
display:block;
}}

}}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use the jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn functions? :https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/, this is the official documentation link, in your case, maybe this might work:

```
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop()>height){
      header_f_wrapper.fadeIn('slow',function(){
      //do something here
     }else{
           header_f_wrapper.fadeOut('slow',function(){
      //do something else here
         });
        }
```

I don't know if this will exactly work, as I don't know the exact cases, but I hope you get some help from this